# Android screen white components getting black on resume

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing EXTREMELY PECULIAR problem with my android application. I see not a single similar solution anywhere, either on google or on SO.

Here is my screenshot of the app:
[image]

This is normal expected output. But when I exit the app and resume again from launcher, often(say 2 out of 5 times) I happen to get the white components(list view and EditText) like this:

[image]

In this image, I have touched the first element of listview while taking screenshot so that its shown that the listview items are having actual content and not empty.

Here is my layout resource file main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/ll"
              android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="15" android:background="@android:color/white">


    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/edittext" android:layout_weight="2" android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:gravity="center" android:hint="Enter Your Text Here"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="2"
            android:weightSum="12" android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Tweet"
                android:id="@+id/tweetbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_weight="6"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Search"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:id="@+id/searchbtn"
                android:layout_weight="6"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Most Frequently Tweeted"
            android:id="@+id/listviewlabel" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center" android:background="#adadad"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <ListView
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="10"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please someone help me out with this. Atleast help me resolve the white EditText issue first. That will give me alteast a clue to solve the listview issue.

EDIT:
The listview is dynamically populated by elements. Here is my onStart() method:

```
@Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        handleFrequentMenuSelected();
    }
```

Here is the handleFrequentMenuSelected():

```
private void handleFrequentMenuSelected() {
        if(!isAccountAdded()){
            showToast("Add an account first to get started! Goto Menu and select account.");
        }else{
            List<StatusElement>aList=getStatusElementsFromSQLiteDatabase();
            HashMap<String,Integer> hMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for(StatusElement s:aList){
                String tokens[]=s.toString().split(" ");
                String outText="";
                if(tokens.length>1){
                    if(tokens[0].contains("/")){
                        String tokens2[]=tokens[0].split("/");
                        try{
                            long l=Long.parseLong(tokens2[0]);
                            for(int i=1;i<tokens.length;i++){
                                outText=outText+tokens[i]+" ";
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            outText=s.toString();
                        }
                    }else{
                        try{
                            long l=Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
                            for(int i=1;i<tokens.length;i++){
                                outText=outText+tokens[i]+" ";
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            outText=s.toString();
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    outText=s.toString();
                }
                outText=outText.trim();
                if(hMap.containsKey(outText)){
                    int cnt=hMap.get(outText);
                    cnt++;
                    hMap.put(outText,cnt);
                }else{
                    hMap.put(outText,1);
                }
            }
            hMap= (HashMap<String, Integer>) StaticConstants.sortByValue(hMap);
            ArrayList<String>tweets=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Integer>frequencies=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayAdapter<String>adapter;

            int count=0;
            for(String s:hMap.keySet()){
                tweets.add(s);
                frequencies.add(hMap.get(s));
                count++;
                if(count==50)
                    break;
            }
            adapter=new MyCustomFrequentArrayAdapter(this,tweets,frequencies);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listViewLabel.setText("Most Frequent Tweets");
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    editText.setText(System.currentTimeMillis()+" "+item);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my MyCustomFrequentArrayAdapter:

```
class MyCustomFrequentArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<String> values;
        private final ArrayList<Integer>frequencies;

        public MyCustomFrequentArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values,ArrayList<Integer>frequencies) {
            super(context, R.layout.customlistview, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
            this.frequencies=frequencies;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistview, parent, false);
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            Log.d("Position",""+position);
            //Extracting first six words
            String s=values.get(position);
            String tokens[]=s.split(" ");
            String dispText="";
            if(tokens.length>6){
                for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
                    dispText=dispText+tokens[i]+" ";
                }
            }else{
                dispText=s;
            }
            textView2.setText(dispText);
            textView1.setText("Frequency:"+frequencies.get(position));
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change both (default) occurrences of: `android:textColor="@android:color/black"` to white...

Comment: @alfasin i changed android:textColor="@android:color/white" . Still same effect :(

Comment: clean the project and re-build

Comment: @alfasin did it over 10 times still nothing.

Comment: It doesn't happen by itself... either your cache is not clean, or you set it to black elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Are you touching the layout (or anything in the layout) from code, or are you simply calling setContentView() in your onCreate()?

Comment: @alfasin if I set it to black in code, then 5 out of 5 times it must be in black, which is not the case.

Comment: @alanv yes I m touching the layout listview from code. The listview items are dynamically populated. Check the edit for onStart().

Comment: a) False. If you set it in the code only on a specific event, for example, it won't happen 5 out of 5 times. b) I don't see any code...

Comment: @alfasin chk again. Perhaps some delay in propagating edits. And I dont set it for specific event. And anyways, I am nowhere touching the EditText's layout properties. So why it is getting black?

Comment: Well, it seems that the change is not coming from this method. Check all the places in the code where you do something with `edittext`.

Comment: @rahulserver : Try changing the `cacheColorHint` for the `ListView` to `#ffffff`

Comment: @alfasin I did ctrl+f to find that only getText/setText is used in the code. Nothing else on editText.

Comment: @Squonk I dont think that will work. Because its not only listview that is getting blackened. The EditText is also the culprit.

Comment: @rahulserver: Try it. There may actually be separate issues for the `EditText` and `ListView`. The `ListView` class is known to have problems if you set a custom background color.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing a blog post by Romain Guy - [Why Is My List Black](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

`ListView` has top and bottom fading edges to indicate it is scrollable.

Creating the fading edge has performance issues so `ListView` has an optimization to improve performance. Unfortunately the optimization causes problems if the background of the `ListView` is set to something other than the default.

The optimization can be disabled by setting `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` as you are doing BUT quoting from the blog post...

> To fix this issue, all you have to do is either **disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background**, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value.

In other words using `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` should only be used for a "non-solid color" (one which is transparent / translucent).

In your case you are using `#ffffff` which is an RGB value and by default that means its 'A' component (the alpha) will be `ff` making it fully opaque, i.e., "solid".

So referring to the last part of the above quote...

> ...set the hint to the appropriate solid color value.

This suggests you should use `android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"` to fix the `ListView` problem.

Comment: I have read that blog post. Romain Guy is also on SO. I went through his posts as well.

Comment: @rahulserver : So have you tried using `#ffffff` for the `cacheColorHint` of the `ListView`?